# Short story horror anthology with "The Thing in the Cellar" and "The Whistle"

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'll take any help I can get! I read a short story horror book when I was young but I don't  remember the title or author. I believe it was a 90's book with a purple or dark cover with a creepy black tree. Two of the story names I can remember are "The Thing in the Cellar" and "The Whistle". I've done countless searches with no luck.

Answer (score 10):

There are a few possibilities:

There is a book titled *Tales From Underwood* published in 1952 which contains a story titled "The Thing in the Cellar" by David H. Keller, originally published in 1932. While this anthology does not contain a story titled "The Whistle" it *does* feature stories with similar titled (e.g. "The Doorbell"). According to the Internet Speculative Fiction Database, this story has also appeared in a variety of other horror anthologies, and while none of those listed features a story titled "The Whistle", *The Century's Best Horror Fiction 1901–1950* features a story titled "The Whistling Room." Here is the cover to this last volume:

[image]

There is also a story titled "The Thing in the Cellar" by Blake Smith, published in *Weird Tales* Fall, 2012. There is no tale titled "The Whistle" or similar in this collection.

There are in addition a number of short stories titled "The Whistle" by different authors including, Ralph Milne Farley (*Weird Tales*, November 1932), Lenora K. Rogers (Dark Matter #3, 1998), M. R. James (*Room 13, and Other Ghost Stories*, 2005), and Hugh Walpole (*All Souls' Night*, 1933).

There are also stories titled **"The Whistler"** by August Derleth (*Weird Tales*, 1930; and *That is Not Dead: The Black Magic & Occult Stories by August Derleth*, 2005), and Dana Pearson (*Northern Haunts*, 2009). ***Northern Haunts*** also features a story titled **"Down the Cellar"** by Joseph Grant. Here is its cover art:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

I set out searching for this last night too and your description matched the book I was searching for. Finally came across it today. I think you’re looking for *World’s Best “True” Ghost Stories* by CB Colby.

Comment: I was not able to find a table of contents anywhere...
According to its AbeBooks profile the book includes 48 stories https://www.abebooks.com/9780806968766/Worlds-Best-True-Ghost-Stories-0806968761/plp
According to an Amazon review, this collection does include a (apparently memorable) story called "The Whistle" https://www.amazon.com/Worlds-Best-True-Ghost-Stories/dp/0806968982
So between that and the apparently solid match to the cover as described, this is a very strong suggestion.